# What is the 1.24TB storage in the Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, storage, sharepoint-online, allocation, sharepointadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQmpo.png)

In the above image, under the admin centre, we can see the storage as 1.24TB, when 'Active Sites' is selected.
What this storage is?

Answer (score 0):

It's the total and available storage space for your organization. Check below docs for more details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits#view-the-total-and-available-storage-space-for-your-organization

Basically, the amount of Microsoft SharePoint space your organization has is based on your number of licenses:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

Related: [Add storage space for your subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/add-storage-space?view=o365-worldwide)

BR

Comment: But as per the link, the total space for the organization is 1TB and here I see 1.24TB. And 10GB for each purchased license.

Comment: (1024G(1TB)+ 10 G X 25 ) / 1024 G= 1.244140625 ≈ 1.24 T

Comment: Yes, got it. I have 24 licenses under subscription. Thank you.

Comment: @shrutikaingale - If answer helpful, mark it and upvote.